# Qt detecting mouse click on titleBar (Windows)

Tags: qt, winapi

event or mousePressEvent functions works for inside of a widget but I want to catch when clicked on a titleBar (upper part of menuBar, contains close button etc.)

How can I do that?

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/8922/solved-how-to-catch-mouse-click-event-on-titlebar-area-of-qmainwindow/4

Comment: The question has clear signs of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a dialog that is minimized in its parent window when escape button pressed. I want to maximize it back if mouse clicked in its titleBar area.

Comment: @iinspectable his question was about coordinates and you answered with a link about an XY Problem, I thought you were on to a classic computer science problem about getting coordinates in a different origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override nativeEvent, then get mouse position to compare with geometry (exclude window frame) and frameGeometry (include window frame) to detect if it hits title bar or not

```
bool MyClass::nativeEvent(const QByteArray & eventType, void * message, long * result)
{
    MSG* msg = (MSG*)(message);
    if (msg->message == WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN)
    {

        int mouseX = GET_X_LPARAM(msg->lParam);
        int mouseY = GET_Y_LPARAM(msg->lParam);
        QRect frame = frameGeometry();
        QRect content = geometry();

        qDebug() << "mouseX: " << mouseX << "mouseY:" << mouseY;
        qDebug() << "frame: " << frame;
        qDebug() << "content: " << content;

        if (mouseY < content.y() && mouseY >= frame.y())
        {
            qDebug() << "Hit title bar";
        }
    }

    *result = 0;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the PyQt implementation.

```py
from  PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from  PyQt5.QtCore import *

import ctypes.wintypes
import logging
from win32con import *
import win32api

class W(QTabWidget):
    def nativeEvent(self, eventType, message):
        click_menu = QMenu(self)
        click_menu.addAction("Yay")

        try:
            msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG.from_address(message.__int__())
        except:
            logging.error("", exc_info=True)
        if eventType == "windows_generic_MSG":
            if msg.message == WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_x = win32api.LOWORD(msg.lParam)
                mouse_y = win32api.HIWORD(msg.lParam)
                frame = self.frameGeometry()
                content = self.geometry()
                print(mouse_x, mouse_y, frame, content)
                if mouse_y < content.y() and mouse_y >= frame.y():

                    click_menu.exec_(QPoint(mouse_x, mouse_y))

        return False, 0

app = QApplication([])

w = W()
w.resize(1000,100)
w.move(0,0)
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

One thing I can't figure out about this, what happens to my menu if I click the titlebar again without clicking the menu.
The menu disappears, which is then allows me to move the titlebar when clicking - which is good...but I can't reliably bring the menu back up