# Minimized dialog's frameGeometry (titleBar)

Tags: c++, qt

I have a dialog that is minimized in its parent window. When I call frameGeometry() the result is active dialog's(not minimized) numbers.

I want to know where the titleBar is. (when dialog minimized just shown titleBar of the dialog)

Comment: Can you give a sample code?

Comment: @PhạmAnhTuấn It is the same code you wrote in my another question :) mouseX: 949 mouseY:375---
frame: 752 355---
content: 760 386---
Hit title bar------------------------------------------------
mouseX: 88 mouseY:1025---
frame: 752 355---
content: 760 386---    These are outputs. First ones are active window's numbers, second ones are minimized ones. But as you can see frame and content are the same for both minimized and active.

Comment: Oh, how can you minimize qwiget in its parent? And how can it just show title bar when minimize?

Comment: @PhạmAnhTuấn It is a QDialog. I use setWindowState(Qt::WindowState::WindowMinimized); if escape button is pressed. I am adding a snapshot what it looks like [ss-link](https://imgur.com/a/dB0t4) You can see at bottom left

Comment: Show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), if the same code of another question copied here, we are not following your questions.

Comment: If the Dialog only shows its title bar, why do you need to check if mouse clicks on its title bar? If the Dialog caughts mouse click event, does the event certainly hit on its title bar?

Comment: @eyllanesc [here is the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111579/qt-detecting-mouse-click-on-titlebar-windows)

Comment: @PhạmAnhTuấn Dialog cannot caught mouse click event when it is minimized

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

header file

```
#ifndef MYDIALOG_H
#define MYDIALOG_H

#include <QtWidgets/QDialog>
#include <QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h>
class MyDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyDialog();

protected:
    virtual bool nativeEvent(const QByteArray & eventType, void * message, long * result);

};

class MyWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public: 
    MyWindow();
    ~MyWindow();

private:
    MyDialog * m_dialog;

};

#endif // MYDIALOG_H
```

source file

```
#include "mydialog.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>
MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    setStyleSheet("QDialog{background-color: red}");
}

MyDialog::~MyDialog()
{

}

bool MyDialog::nativeEvent(const QByteArray & eventType, void * message, long * result)
{
    MSG* msg = (MSG*)(message);
    if (msg->message == WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        if (isMinimized())
        {
            QTimer::singleShot(50, this, SLOT(showNormal()));
            *result = 0;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            int mouseX = GET_X_LPARAM(msg->lParam);
            int mouseY = GET_Y_LPARAM(msg->lParam);

            QRect frame = frameGeometry();
            QRect content = geometry();

            qDebug() << "frame: " << frame;
            qDebug() << "content: " << content;

            if (mouseY < content.y() && mouseY >= frame.y())
            {
                qDebug() << "Hit title bar";
                showMinimized();
            }
        }
    }

    *result = 0;
    return false;
}

MyWindow::MyWindow()
    :QMainWindow()
{
    setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{background-color: blue}");
    showMaximized();
    m_dialog = new MyDialog(this);
    m_dialog->showMinimized();
}

MyWindow::~MyWindow()
{
}
```